# Open object type gets unified too soon

Tags: types, ocaml

I have a large `let` block which handle a lot of computation, and I'm trying to break it down into smaller pieces by factoring out chunks of it into functions. I need to pass a function which operates on open objects to those components, and am running into annoyances best expressed in the simplified code below:

```
type 'a foo = 'a
  constraint 'a = < bar: string option; .. >

type foo' = < bar: string option; >

type bar = < bar: int option; qux: int option >

type ('a, 'b) fn = 'a foo -> 'b foo

let a = object method bar = None method qux = None end
let b = object method bar = None end

(* Doesn't work *)
let xyz fn =
  let res = fn a in
  let res' = fn b in
  res, res'

(* Doesn't work *)
let xyz (fn:('a, 'b) fn) =
  let res = fn a in
  let res' = fn b in
  res, res'

(* Doesn't work *)
type fn' = foo' -> foo'
let xyz (fn:fn') =
  let res = fn a in
  let res' = fn b in
  res, res'

(* Sub-par solution: imagine needing several of these conversions across several
   functions, which is the situation I have when trying to decompose a large let
   block into component functions like xyz. *)
let xyz (fn:('a, 'b) fn) =
  let res = fn (a :> foo') in
  let res' = fn b in
  res, res'

(* Another sub-par solution: *)
type ('a, 'b) fn'' = { fn: 'a. 'a foo -> 'b foo }
let xyz (fn:('a, 'b) fn'') =
  let fn = fn.fn in
  let res = fn a in
  let res' = fn b in
  res, res'

(* What I want: *)
type ('a, 'b) fn''' = 'a. 'a foo -> 'b foo
let xyz (fn:('a, 'b) fn''') =
  let res = fn a in
  let res' = fn b in
  res, res'


(* What I am currently using (don't pass the function around to HOFs: keep the
   computation all in a massive let statement. *)
let _ =
  let a : foo = object method bar = None method qux = None end in
  let b : bar = object method bar = None end in
  let fn a = object method bar = a#bar method qux = None end in
  (* fn gets the correctly inferred type of < bar : 'a; .. > -> < bar : 'a; qux : 'b option > *)
  fn a, fn b
```

Any guidance, or just reasons as to why what I want is impossible/assurance that it is indeed possible right now/promises that one day—in a brighter world—this will work, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to use function arguments polymorphically inside the definition: i.e. applying `fn` to two values of different object types inside `xyz`.  This is called Rank-2 polymorphism (https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types) but is not supported in Hindley Milner type system (it can only handle Rank-1).  OCaml is based on Hindley Milner and does not support Rank-N directly either.

Currently OCaml support of Rank-2 polymorphism is very indirect: simulation via polymorphic record members, without any type inference. I guess your "Another sub-par solution" is the best way here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and the reference to Rank-N types. Why is it that the type inference works when inside of a function (last example), or wrapped in a record type (my "another sub-par solution")? It doesn't work when just a top-level function, nor does it work within an object (`< fn: 'a. 'a foo -> 'b foo >`). Additionally, do you know if something like this is in scope for OCaml to support? Finally (and thank you for bearing with me), were you in this situation, you would wrap the function in a record type?

Comment: The last example works since it does not require Rank-2 polymoprhism: you do not pass `fn` to a HOF.  There is no magic in "another sub-par solution", you give the the polymorphic type of `fn` by yourself at the polymorphic record type definition which OCaml's type system cannot infer.

Comment: `type 'b fn''_by_object = < fn : 'a. 'a foo -> 'b foo >;;   let xyz (fn : 'b fn''_by_object) = fn#fn a, fn#fn b` should work fine.

Comment: You can google "ocaml rank 2 polymorphism" to see several literatures.  And yes, if I need to simulate Rank-2, I use polymorphic record fields.